# combing multiple files to a single tar file through python

Tags: python, linux, windows

My requirement is that I need to combine multiple files placed in some directory of windows to a single .tar file in the same directory. I need to do this with the help of python script. Can anyone help me how to explore this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the documentation [**High-level file operations > Archiving operations**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#archiving-example) or [**Read and write tar archive files > Examples**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html?highlight=tarfile#examples)